# LoginAndEnrollAccount(emailText) does not prompts the email and password with updated Intune SDK

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal, adal, intune

Ours is an Intune Application with Xamarin forms.
Authentication is handled default by Intune SDK.
Application does not use ADAL nor MSAL.

after the Intune SDK update, LoginAndEnrollAccount does not prompts the user for username and password.

when the Intune SDK 14.3.5 version is used it prompts for username and password and Login is successful.

Help is appreciated

When tried with 14.3.5 Login is successful.
When tried with 17.1.1 Login is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by upgrading to the latest Intune version i.e. Version 17.7.3.0 and MSAL settings.